# jQuery qtip() - how to get the id from the clicked item

Tags: jquery, qtip

I have the jQuery qtip() function in my asp.net page and I need to get the id from the clicked item. Does anyone know how to do it?

As an example, please find below my script code...

```
$("#content a.toolTip").qtip({
     content: { url: 'PageView.aspx?Param=' + '---get id---'  }
)};
```

Thanks in advance.

[]'rpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to reference the element via `this` when setting up the qtip, you could do your setup inside of an `.each()`. That way `this` refers to the current element.

```
$("#content a.toolTip").each(function() {
        // Now "this" is a reference to the
        //    element getting the qtip
        // Get the ID attribte -------------------------------v
    $(this).qtip({ content: { url: 'PageView.aspx?Param=' + this.id } });
});
```

Comment: upvote from the future - saved much headache on getting data-property value for calling ajax to populate tool tip content

Answer (score 0):

$("#content a.toolTip").qtip({

content: { url: 'PageView.aspx?Param=' + $( this ).attr( 'id' ) }

)};

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but I've done this before and it didn't seem to work. I only got an "undefined" string from javascript.

Comment: Here the `this` keyword is most likely referring to the `document` context instead of the actual element. :o)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get some parameters, you can cheat like this ;)

```
$("#content a.toolTip").each(function()
{
    $(this).qtip({
        content: { url: 'PageView.aspx?Param=' + $(this).attr('id')  }
    });
});
```